# How can I change a Text color in Blender?

Tags: color, text-object

I did in Object Mode > Add > Text
Now I want to change the text color to red. Now it's in gray.

[image: Blender text color change]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: wrong forum for this question but you can google: "blender change object text color"

Comment: If there is no [material, add one](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/materials/material_panel.html) and set the diffuse colour to red. Note that configuring materials varies depending on which [render engine](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/introduction.html#render-engines) you select.

Comment: there is nothing off topic about this question.  He's asking how to change the color of his text.  what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Millard that comment has been migrated of [SO]

Comment: oh, that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using an older version of Blender. You should download a newer one, however, you should still be able to follow this, because it's basically the same in your version, except your tab icons are on the top, instead of the side of that panel, as below.

Change tabs and add new shader
[image: Change tabs and add new shader]

Click the default white color for a pallet wheel
[image: Click the default white color for a pallet wheel]

Choose you color
[image: Choose you color]

Comment: Don't forget to change the view to *Preview/Render*, else you will not notice the change in color https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCSg5.png